# What is the past and past participle of "lift off" when used as a verb?

Tags: irregular-forms

Five, four, three, two, one, zero… We have lift-off.

Though "lift-off" here is being used as a hyphened noun, 'lift off' is used as a verb.

Just lifted off?

Comment: In "lift off", "lift" is a regular verb and "off" is a preposition.

Comment: @GorttheRobot "off" is an adverb- a word that, on its own, modifies a verb. Prepositions must be followed by a noun to make an adverbial phrase, which then modifies the verb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Lift off" is a phrasal verb, meaning it consists of a verb and a particle (either a preposition or an adverb). The past and past participle forms are both "lifted off" as in

> There was a burst of flame as the rocket lifted off into the sky.

Please see
https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/lift-off